# Half of the letters of all of the words are missing

Tags: manjaro

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, but it's pretty weird and it just started happening out of the blue.

Suddenly half of the letters of all the words displayed anywhere on my screen are missing.

Interestingly, the question edit box seems to be unaffected.

I've attached an image of the problem, but just in case you can't see it an example would be:

Th s is a s nte ce wi h s me  f th  let  rs m ssi g.

[image: Missing Letters]

I'm running Manjaro XFCE 16.06 x64 on an old HPG62. It might just be my laptop packing up, but like I said. The edit box is normal.

## Edit

I may not have made it clear, but the problem is not just specific to the browser in the screenshot. It is system wide. Anywhere there is text some of the letters are missing. If I close and reopen a menu different letters are missing.

There are two exceptions that I have seen. One is the edit box on this site and the other is the text inside the sublime text 3 editor. In those two cases the text is rendered normally.

Comment: have you tried to reproduce issue with another browser ? it can be also an outdated video driver issue

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170854/hector-maddock-greene and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170861/hector.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Intel video driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from work today and tuning my laptop on I've found that the problem has solved itself. It's the first time I've ever had that problem on any machine.

My best guess is that it had something to do with overheating. My laptop does have a tendency to get pretty hot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if chrome is using the correct character encoding:

https://support.google.com/news/answer/61689?hl=en

set it to Unicode UTF-8